# ios use different images on iPhon4s vs iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have two images that I want to display.  One that is sized for a iPhone 4s and one for a 5/5s.  I have named the images display.png and display@2x.png thinking that the lower resolution iPhone 4s would show display.png and the iPhone 5s would show display@2x.png. However, both phones show display@2x.png and the image is cutoff on the iPhone 4s.

How can make my app distinguish between the two different sized files?

Comment: Are these images being used for the launch image?

Comment: @68cherries if these images were launch images then they would be named `default.png` and `default@2x.png` so no they aren't launch images.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Asset Catalog in Xcode 5+

[image]

2x is for 4s and R4 for iphone 5

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) and the [Apple iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW8) launch images that have `-568h` at the end will be used for iPhone5.

> At runtime, the system looks for a launch image whose name contains the -568h modifier. If such an image is present, the system assumes that your app supports the iPhone 5 explicitly and runs it in fullscreen mode.

Images with the suffix `-568h` should be used for iPhone 5 screen size, images with `@2x` suffix will be for non-iPhone 5 screens but all other retina screens and finally images without a suffix are for non-retina screen devices such as iPhone 3GS. Check out the Apple Documentation above for a description of every image size and resolution and what the names should contain.

You can use the assets catalog to help you set these images up and the correct names, check out the [Apple Documentation on Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1).

For none launch images that don't pick up the `-568h` here is a little macro to help you out.

```
#define ASSET_SCREEN_SIZE(normal, stretched) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? normal : stretched)
```

then all you need do is call

```
UIImage *imageToUse = [UIImage imageNamed:ASSET_SCREEN_SIZE(@"myImage", @"myImage-568h")];
```

Comment: Great, thanks @Popeye! But you have to close a square bracket after bounds word in the #define.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to have two images. The "@2x" designation is for the difference between a retina and a non-retina screen. If you want different images for different devices, you need to have different images with different names.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4s is retina and so get the image ending with `@2x` if exists.

So you should check if is an iPhone 5 and so load the properly image (that you can call with a particular end name).

To use a clean and well structured code, 
I would **subclass the UIImage** (or using category) creating a new method and then returning the appropriate image after checking if is an iPhone 5, calling `[UIImage imageNamed:newName];`

For example having images like:

```
name
name@2x
name-h568
```

Use this function:

```
#import "UIImage+ScreenSize.h"

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

@implementation UIImage (ScreenSize)


+ (UIImage *)imageScreenNamed:(NSString *)name {

    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        name = [name stringByAppendingString:@"-h568"]; //Or your favorite suffix
    }

    return [[self class] imageNamed:name];
}

@end
```

calling:

```
[UIImage imageScreenNamed:@"name"];
```

Comment: Why would you do this? How would you check that the image is correct? Overriding this method seems awfully unstable to me, especially since you're trying to make two non-equivalent items act as if they're equivalent. At the very least, he should do a category on UIImage and make a NEW method that handles sorting out the correct image/device logic. Maybe '-(UIImage *)deviceSpecificImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName'. He could then name his images with an '@Retina35' or '@Retina4' suffix to differentiate. Still, seems like a bad fit for this issue.

Comment: Edited with an example

Answer (score 0):

Because iphone4s is also using retina screen, so they will use display@2x.png image instead of  display.png.  (assume you use "display@2x.png" for iphone5, and use "display.png" for iphone 4s. p.s you should name them like "iphone5.png" and "iphone4.png" instead.)

1 So what you need to do is checking the size of height of this device, do sth like this:

> #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ]
>   bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

then: use it as:

> if (IS_IPHONE_5) { //use display@2x.png } else { //use display.png }

2 Not sure about this one works:

You can try adding image named "display-568h@2x.png" for iphone5 version.

Comment: This still misses the point that the user wants to override a built-in function. That's bad form.

Comment: @mbm29414b where the user said he want to override a built-in function? his propose is just want to "distinguish between the two different sized files", and I post what he wants. Thank you~

Comment: He wants to change the built-in functionality of the "@2x" suffix. How is that not wanting to change a built-in function?

Comment: @mbm29414 Read the question carefully please. He misunderstand about retina of iphone4 and iphone5 there. It is not quiet related to "@2x". What he wants is the solution to distinguish between the two different sized files.

Comment: Please re-read your answer. You clearly tell him to use the images he has named 'display.png' and 'display@2x.png', which violates/breaks built-in functionality that Apple provides. That may not be your intent, but I can only respond what you've actually written.

Comment: @mbm29414 he can rename them as I said.